# Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types can't be convertible

Tags: c#, mudblazor

What's Wrong with my code? I'm getting error like this:
CS1662  Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Using blazor webassembly project. I have installed mudblazor.
I'm getting output in web api but here it show error message like this.

````
    @using BlazorApp1.Shared
    @using BlazorApp1.Shared.Models
    @using BlazorApp1.Client.Services.Interface
    @inject HttpClient Http

    <MudTable Items="@items" Hover="true" 
           Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" Loading="@_loading" 
           LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
   <HeaderContent>
   <MudTh>UserID</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Person  ID</MudTh>
   <MudTh>First Name</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Last Name</MudTh>
   <MudTh>UPN</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Email</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Manager user ID</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Status</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Phone Number</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Country Code</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Country</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Region</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Business Unit</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Category</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Title</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Admin Role</MudTh>
   <MudTh>IsManager</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Azure Object Id</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Group Of</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Site Code</MudTh>
   <MudTh>Department</MudTh>
   <MudTh>DateCreated</MudTh>
   <MudTh>DateModified</MudTh>
   </HeaderContent>
   <RowTemplate>
   <MudTd DataLabel="UserId">@context.UserId</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="PersonID">@context.PersonId</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="FirstName">@context.FirstName</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="LastName">@context.LastName</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="UPN">@context.Upn</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="Email">@context.Email</MudTd>
   <MudTd 
    DataLabel="ManagerUserID">@context.ManagerUserId</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="Status">@context.Status</MudTd>
   <MudTd 
    DataLabel="PhoneNumber">@context.PhoneNumber</MudTd>
   <MudTd 
   DataLabel="CountryCode">@context.CountryCode</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="Country">@context.Country</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="Region">@context.Region</MudTd>
   <MudTd 
    DataLabel="BusinessUnit">@context.BusinessUnit</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="Category">@context.Category</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="Title">@context.Title</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="AdminRole">@context.AdminRole</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="IsManager">@context.IsManager</MudTd>
   <MudTd 
    DataLabel="AzureObjectID">@context.AzureObjectId</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="GroupOf">@context.GroupOf</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="SiteCode">@context.SiteCode</MudTd>
   <MudTd DataLabel="Department">@context.Department</MudTd>
   <MudTd 
    DataLabel="DateCreated">@context.DateCreated</MudTd>
   <MudTd 
    DataLabel="DateModified">@context.DateModified</MudTd>

   
   </RowTemplate>
   </MudTable>
   <MudSwitch @bind-Checked="_hidePosition">Hide 
   <b>position</b> when Breakpoint=Xs</MudSwitch>
   <MudSwitch @bind-Checked="_loading">Show 
    Loading</MudSwitch>
   @code {
   private bool _hidePosition;
   private bool _loading;
   private bool isVisible = true;
   [Inject]
   public IUserTableService usertableservice { get; set; }
   private IEnumerable<UserTable> items { get; set; } = new 
   List<UserTable>();

   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
       await Getuser();
   }
   protected async Task Getuser() 
   {
       items = await usertableservice.GetUsers() as 
   List<UserTable>;
       StateHasChanged();
   }
   
   } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error (CS1662) with my own MudTable.

After a while, I found that my error was caused due to my mistakenly trying to use a property that did not exist in `@context` in a `MudTd`.

For example: using `@context.Name` instead of `@context.FullName`, where `.Name` did not exist in the model used to populate the table.

So, the first thing I would do in your circumstance is double check all your properties being referenced in your MudTd's are correct.

I don't know if this will also solve your problem, but I hope it helps.